# Three Boxes wont line up

Tags: html, css

I can't figure out why these three boxes can't line up. I have tried everything but no luck.

I setup jfiddle I think it might be easy for you to see that way. The problem is the middle box is sagging.

The middle box:

```
 <div class="bg-3">
 <div class="indent">
 <div class="wrapper margin-bot"><img title="duralume new" src="http://www.webstertoolbox.com/media/wysiwyg/images/NEw.png" alt="new" width="62" height="52" /><a href="http://www.webstertoolbox.com/index.php/products/duralume-collection-usa.html"><img style="padding-left: 34px;"           src="http://www.webstertoolbox.com/media/wysiwyg/images/duralume.gif" alt="" width="144"      height="33" /></a>
 <div class="extra-wrap">&nbsp;</div>
 </div>
 <ul class="ul-1">
 <li><span style="font-family: 'trebuchet ms', geneva;">Expert Domestic Tech      Support</span></li>
 <li><span style="font-family: 'trebuchet ms', geneva;">Made in USA</span></li>
 <li><span style="font-family: 'trebuchet ms', geneva;">Custom solutions</span></li>
 <li><span style="font-family: 'trebuchet ms', geneva;">On-site Engineers</span></li>
 </ul>
 <a class="button-1 margin-left"      href="http://www.webstertoolbox.com/index.php/products/duralume-collection-usa.html">Click      to Order Now!</a></div>
 </div>
```

You can find it here: http://jsfiddle.net/GWUDG/

Here are the full results: http://jsfiddle.net/GWUDG/embedded/result/

Let me know if you have any questions.

Thanks,
Frank G.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go, [edited your Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GWUDG/1/)

Main change is:

```
.bg-3 {
  display: block;
  float: left;
}
```

You need to clear the floats on the `.wrapper`

```
.floatstop:after {
    clear: both;
    content: ".";
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
}
:first-child + html .floatstop {
    min-height: 1px;
}
* html .floatstop {
    height: 1%;
}

<div class="wrapper floatstop margin-bot1">
```